# font color for string value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to apply font color to the string value in JavaScript. How do I? 
I tried like below: I want the search text in red color.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var defaultText="search";
    defaultText.text.color="red";
});
```

Comment: Where you want to put it then? Show expected HTML.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although your question isn't quite according the SO standards (try to read the rules), I think @chandresh_cool provided the correct answer.

Comment: @Baszz did you try it? It is not correct.

Comment: `defaultText` is a string, you cannot change the color of a string value

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev No, I did not...and you are right. I assumed it was some kind of DOM node. The way it is in the question, it will not work indeed :)

Comment: why should you color a string unless you are Chuck Norris? :)

Comment: You can create css class for apply text color red. You can use add or remove this class using css.

Comment: You cannot assign font color for string. You can assign font color for a DOM Element which contains this string such as `SPAN`, `DIV`...

Comment: Actually there is search box,i want to add the 'search' text inside that box,i did that.now i wanna change the color of that text.can anybody help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only change the color of DOM element.In your case it is not
DOM variable.It is a string you are not showing any where in the
html.So it is not possible to apply color to that string .If you apply
color also  where you will see that color.

Comment: I guess the downvote is for the un-edited answer. anyway your answer should really be only a comment...

Comment: Why did you format your whole answer as a quote? Please pay more attention to formatting, you better read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) as well.

Comment: Actually there is search box,i want to add the 'search' text inside that box,i did that.now i wanna change the color of that text.can anybody help

Answer (score 0):

You can use span for holding string search and apply css to this span.

```
<span id="search"></span>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').val('search').css('color','red');
});
```

Comment: Actually there is search box,i want to add the 'search' text inside that box,i did that.now i wanna change the color of that text.can anybody help